# ODBC data connection to excel showing all 1s for number column

Tags: mysql, dataset, odbc, excel-2010

I have a mysql query that pulls into excel via an ODBC connection. This query determines top 5 per group in descending order for the data it pulls and gives it a ranking number (1 through 5 in order of value per each unique item in group).

-- The issue is when the data is imported into Excel, all the values of the 'rank' field are set at 1 (they should vary between 1 and 5), instead of the correct numbers. I've tried a whole host of things, but cannot figure out why excel is doing this.

I'm using mysql, and excel 2010.

Things I've tried:

1) Creating a new connection

2) Casting the rank output as a char

3) Concatenating the rank with text as a string.

4) deleting the worksheet and recreating it.

5) changing the column order in the sql

Thanks for any help you can provide. paraphrased query is below.

```
select
rank,
center,
supervisor_id,
missed,
box,
missed_percent

from
(select
supervisor_id,
missed,
box,
missed_percent,
@ranking := if(@warehouse = center, @ranking + 1,1) as rank,
@warehouse := center as center

from
(select
  a.center,
  f.supervisor_id,
  sum(missed) as missed,
  count(box) as box,
  sum(missed) / count(box) as missed_percent,
  (SELECT @ranking:= 0) s

from
seventy_subquery_table

left join people f on a.employee_id = f.employee_id

group by
a.center,
f.supervisor_id

) m
order by center, missed_percent desc
) m2

where m2.rank <= 5
order by center, rank
```

Comment: Have you verified the data is correct in the database?  Not only that the values are actually different than 1 but to see the table structure and make sure your querying the right table or field?

Comment: Hey Owen, the rank(which is what is not correct) is what is generated by the query itself, and not stored in a table. When I run query all the values are correct and also show correctly when I manually export to excel.

Comment: please post some code then.  specifically the query.

Comment: The query works great, but I posted it for you as well.

Comment: ya sorry, im not sure.  especially if the query is working.  the only other thing i can say to troubleshoot with is to try a newer or older version of excel.  ill vote up ur post in hope that gets you some more views.

Comment: Thanks for your help Owen.

I actually just figured it out! The issue is within the second wrapping subquery - Apparently the ODBC connection to excel executes logically different then running it in mysql. So in this case something could work when ran, but no through ODBC.

So where mysql is shows correct data, excel doesn't

Adding  (SELECT @warehouse:= '') to the second subquery fixed the issue! I hope someone else can learn from this as it was frustrating.

I'll post this same information when SO lets me self answer my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just figured it out! The issue is within the second wrapping subquery - Apparently the ODBC connection to excel executes logically different then running it in mysql. So in this case something could work when ran, but no through ODBC.

Where mysql is shows correct data, excel doesn't Adding (SELECT @warehouse:= '') to the second subquery fixed the issue! I hope someone else can learn from this as it was frustrating